# How to start a line chart at 0 in excel

Tags: ms-office, graph

I am in dire need of a solution for the Break Even chart that i have created using Microsoft Excel. Can anyone please tell me how to start the blue line (NPV of all benefits) from 0 instead of Year 0. the image has been attached. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the spreadsheet to start at 0 instead of year-0 you can do one of 2 things. Change the label "Year-0" to just "0" or add another pair of points as the very first entry. Make the x-value whatever it should be and set the label name as "0" and the y value forthis new point is whatever it is.